# C++ Qt "Go to Slot" Missing

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface

My Qt designer which is integrated with Visual Studio 2015 enterprise, does not function properly. I've seen many tutorials where people show right clicking on a control, and then clicking on 'go to slot' to declare the event of for example clicking a button.

My editor however is lacking this feature, how to proceed? Do I have to always manually write all the necessary information about the control and then only I can create the event?

EDIT: The "go to slot" button however shows when I go to Qt Creator (different application???)

So the button shows up on Qt Creator but not in Qt Designer.

Comment: As a guess, that feature is maybe not supported by VS version.  If so, adapt your work flow accordingly: Use Qt Creator on the side (shouldn't be problematic, I suppose both IDEs can be configured to reload externally modified files automatically) or write your slots by hand.

Comment: I have not seen a go to slot when developing Qt applications in Visual Studio. Qt Designer has no connection to the VS IDE.

Answer (score 9):

Qt Designer doesn't implement this feature; the Qt Creator does. Your Qt Designer itself works correctly. It is impossible to implement this without having a full code model etc., so the feature belongs in the IDE: in Qt Creator or in a VS add-in. The Qt VS add-in could offer this feature it, but nobody has submitted any code for this yet, hint hint :)

TL;DR: It's by design.

[image: Smokey the Bear with an "Only You Can Implement It" slogan]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question and looked how the Qt Creator connects the signals.
And here is the Answer: [Post from @Steve Lorimer](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/43918538/2)

> Your slots must conform to the following format:
>
> ```
> void on_<object-name>_<signal-name>(<signal-parameters>);
> ```

I tested it in Visual Studio 2015 and it works fine. Create a slot in this format and it will be connected automatically.

Maybe this works only for migrated projects from Qt Creator into VS, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

Do not forget to include the *.h file of your widget in the CMakelists.txt.
QtCreator needs this to find the Ui::YourWidget

Go to slot function will be able to auto create solt from QtDesigner.